# issue while place the radio buttons inside the liview in android?

Tags: android

I have a listview with radio button. when i click any option and scroll that list view the previous select will cleared.How to do this. The actual problem is when scroll the view on every scorll the view is refreshed, that's why every time the view is refreshed. How to do this I can't get any solution, Plz. Help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your adapter, you are probably don't do the job right on bindView. You have to set again on bindView the values.

I will reformulate the sentence and you will probably will understand.
The newView creates only 5-10 views (as many they fit on the screen), and they are reused for other rows. If you have a ListView with 200 lines in it, actually you have only 5-10 views, and you have to make sure you update the views with the valid changes in bindView. You have to store/save the changes to an object for later reuse.

Comment: There is no bindview concept in android? Plz. give some other example with sample code. Thank U